# Fill TreeView with directories and files on drives

Tags: c++, winapi, treeview, directory, subdirectory

I have got a TreeView in my win32 api project.
I want to fill that TreeView with directories and files on drives. Using one function I get all drives available and then I call this function with the drive letters as parameter:

```
bool ListDirectoryContents(const char *sDir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile;
    HANDLE hFind = 0;
    vector<string> FileNames;

    char sPath[2048];
    sprintf(sPath, "%s\\*.*", sDir);

    if((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir);
        return false;
    }

    do
    {
        if(strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, ".") != 0 && strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, "..") != 0)
        {
            sprintf(sPath, "%s%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName);
            if((fdFile.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            {
                if((fdFile.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0)
                {
                    // Directories
                    AddItemToTree(hwndTree, sPath, 2);
                    //FileNames.insert(sPath);
                    //ListDirectoryContents(sPath); // Recursion
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if((fdFile.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN) == 0)
                {
                    //Files
                    //AddItemToTree(hwndTree, sPath, 2);
                    FileNames.push_back(sPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile));

    FindClose(hFind);

    for(vector<string>::iterator FileName = FileNames.begin(); FileName != FileNames.end(); ++FileName)
    {
        AddItemToTree(hwndTree, (char*)FileName->c_str(), 2);
    }

    return true;
}
```

The vector for FileNames I use to list directories first and files after that.

The function AddItemToTree:

```
HTREEITEM AddItemToTree(HWND hwndTree, char *text, int nLevel)
{
    TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins;
    static HTREEITEM hPrev = (HTREEITEM)TVI_FIRST;
    static HTREEITEM hRootItem = NULL;
    static HTREEITEM hPrevLev2Item = NULL;
    //tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_PARAM;
    tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK;
    tvi.iImage = AddIconToTree(hwndTree, text);
    tvi.iSelectedImage = tvi.iImage;
    tvi.pszText = GetFileNameFromPath(text);
    tvins.hInsertAfter = hPrev;
    tvins.item = tvi;

    if(nLevel == 1)
    {
        tvins.hParent = TVI_ROOT;
    }
    else if(nLevel == 2)
    {
        tvins.hParent = hRootItem;
    }
    else
    {
        TVITEM tviSetup;
        tviSetup.hItem = hPrev;
        tviSetup.mask = TVIF_PARAM;
        TVITEM * tviLocal = &tviSetup;
        TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);

        if(nLevel > tviLocal->lParam)
        {
            tvins.hParent = hPrev;
        }
        else
        {
            HTREEITEM hPrevLocal = TreeView_GetParent(hwndTree, hPrev);
            tviLocal->hItem = hPrevLocal;
            TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);
            for(int i = nLevel; i <= tviLocal->lParam;)
            {
                HTREEITEM hPrevLocalTemp = TreeView_GetParent(hwndTree, hPrevLocal);
                hPrevLocal = hPrevLocalTemp;
                tviLocal->hItem = hPrevLocal;
                TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);
            }
            tviLocal->mask = TVIF_TEXT;
            TreeView_GetItem(hwndTree, tviLocal);
            tvins.hParent = hPrevLocal;

        }
    }

    hPrev = (HTREEITEM)SendMessage(hwndTree, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&tvins);

    if(hPrev == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(nLevel == 1)
    {
        hRootItem = hPrev;
    }

    return hPrev;
}
```

The problem is, that if I used the recursion call in `ListDirectoryContents` function, it would take really long time to fill all the directories and files in the TreeView.

So I thought it could work somehow like so:

- First I would add the roots (all drives such as C:\, D:\...)
- I would find all subdirectories and files in the drives and add them as childs of the drive roots.
- Then if I expanded the root node, it would find all subdirectories of the previously found subdirectories of the drives and so on...

But here comes the problem, how can I insert some item in certain place? I mean what would be the third parameter in the `AddItemToTree` function?

Is there any simpler way to fill TreeView with directories?
Thank You all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the way you'd do this isn't with a `nLevel` parameter at all, but with a `hItemParent` parameter.

That is, when you call `AddItemToTree` you'd pass the function the `HTREEITEM` corresponding to the parent item. This would get fed through to the `tvins.hParent` member when you insert the new item.

So where you currently have `nLevel == 1`, you'd have `AddItemToTree(hwndTree, "text", TVI_ROOT)`.

To populate a child folder when it's expanded, you need a `WM_NOTIFY` handler that watches for the [`TVN_ITEMEXPANDED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773533(v=vs.85).aspx) notification.

When you get this message, it tells you which item expanded - and this is the parameter you'd pass to `AddItemToTree`.

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
    if (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == TVN_ITEMEXPANDED)
    {
        // work out the path to read, and then ...
        AddItemToTree(hwndTree, <path>, ((LPNMTREEVIEW)lParam)->itemNew.hItem);
    }
```

Comment: There is also a `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` notification, which is triggered before the node is expanded, whereas `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED` is triggered after the node has been expanded. `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` can cancel the expand, for instance, but `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED` cannot. Depending on your app's particular needs, `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` might be a better choice for populating child nodes.

Comment: So what parameter should I pass when I want to make child of TVI_ROOT?
I'm trying to pass TVI_LAST, but that throws me an exception error...I know why, but don't know, how to do that correctly..

Comment: @ProXicT: To make a child of `TVI_ROOT` you pass `TVI_ROOT`. Don't get confused between the `hParent` member which specifies the **parent** item, and the `hInsertAfter` member, which specifies positioning relative to sibling items (and `TVI_LAST` is used for positioning, not to specify the parent).

Comment: Well, I am really confused now, when I want to create a ROOT in treeview, I pass the TVI_ROOT as parameter like so:
    `HTREEITEM AddItemToTree(HWND hwndTree, char *text, HTREEITEM     parent)
    {
     ...
     ...
     tvins.hInsertAfter = hPrev;
     tvins.item = tvi;
     tvins.hParent = parent;

     hPrev = SendM...`
So how I am supposed to make child of TVI_ROOT with the same parameter?

Comment: The root of the tree is the tree before anything has been added to it at all. `TVI_ROOT` isn't an actual item, it just means "add this item at the root level". Everything else is a child of an actual item.

Comment: If you look at [this picture](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC510750.png), `Root node` is a child of `TVI_ROOT`, `NodeA` is a child of `Root node`, `ChildA` is a child of `NodeA`.

Comment: Ok, I get that, but when my root is the hdd, I want to fill that with results found on this hdd, so I can expand the first root. Then when I expand it, I want to add childs to every folder listed in hdd's childs. When I expand something, I can get the handle of the item I expanded if I got it right, but when I don't have anything to expand and need to add some child, how can I get the handle of that parent?

Comment: The `tvins.hInsertAfter` will always be equal to the previously added item, if no item is added yet, it is equal to `TVI_FIRST`, right? And then the `tvins.hParent` will be equal to the parent item, under which item I want to create child, right? If so, how I am able to get the parent handle when I want to create the first child level?

Comment: This is what I have: [picture](http://www.kamdance.cz/TreeView.png) I have really no idea now, how can I make the folders and files as childs of the drives. I just don't know, how to get the `tvins.hParent ` from the drives without WM_NOTIFY.

Comment: I don't really know how else to explain it. Maybe someone else can have a go.

Comment: You helped me a lot indeed, I feel really stupid now :-D Thank You for Your time! Hopefully I will get that soon :-)